# Given no knowledge of var, include both continuous and dummy

Tags: machine-learning, continuous-data, discrete-data

Imagine we have a variable with 5-7 unique values in a machine learning setting. 
One could argue that given no knowledge, we might convert it into 5 dummy variables, or one might consider it continuous.

Dummy would work well when they are clearly distinct categories, continuous would work if it would have a linear relation.

But what about doing both? It might feel a bit redundant, but given no knowledge it might be best not to miss out on anything?

Or should we do a simple pearson test before running a model?

Answer (score 3):

One approach to doing both with ordered categories is to use orthogonal polynomials (this is actually the default with ordered factors in R); it embeds the linear effect in the categorical one without any need for additional coding and the test of linear vs the more general case is simple since you just take all the sums of squares for higher order terms and add the corresponding d.f. and you have a standard partial-F test.

Here's some R code that achieves the same thing several different ways:

```
carsd = cars[cars[,1] %in% c(10,15,20),]
speed.of = ordered(carsd$speed)
catfit = lm(dist~speed.of,carsd)
summary(lm(dist~speed.of,carsd))
Call:
lm(formula = dist ~ speed.of, data = carsd)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-18.400  -7.667   0.000   6.800  20.667 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   36.578      4.031   9.074 1.74e-05 ***
speed.of.L    17.253      6.708   2.572    0.033 *  
speed.of.Q     3.974      7.245   0.548    0.598    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 12.99 on 8 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4814,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3518 
F-statistic: 3.713 on 2 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.07233

linfit = lm(dist~speed,carsd)
anova(linfit,catfit)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: dist ~ speed
Model 2: dist ~ speed.of
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq      F Pr(>F)
1      9 1400.6                           
2      8 1349.9  1    50.752 0.3008 0.5984

anova(lm(dist~speed+speed.of,carsd))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: dist
          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
speed      1 1202.29 1202.29  7.1254 0.02839 *
speed.of   1   50.75   50.75  0.3008 0.59836  
Residuals  8 1349.87  168.73                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Great, nice to see R take care of that automatically. I'm working with Python myself, so I guess I should just add dummies and a continuous variable to a model and allow one variation to be dropped?

Comment: @Pascal Well as my example doing it two different ways showed, you can do it without fitting both models at once. If you employ the orthogonal polynomial approach and if you can get the sums of squares for each term in turn, that would let you do it in one fit. If you just do it using straight dummies, because the linear fit is encompassed by the model with all dummies, you can take the residual SS for each fit and calculate $F=\frac{(\text{SSE}_\text{linear}-\text{SSE}_\text{dummy})}{(g-2)\cdot \text{MSE}_\text{dummy}}$ for where $g$ is the number of levels in the dummy model.

Comment: @Pascal So you may be able to make it work the way you suggest (I haven't done regression in Python), but if that doesn't do what is needed there are many ways you can get the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure myself: I just want given, say, 100 variables, to allow also this idea of continuous+dummy options. I would also allow for higher terms (interactions, polynomial), so I doubt it is the most efficient to compare the 2 models for each such term (in combination with each possible interaction). That would be a lot of model fitting. I'm now heading to the idea of adding a continuous variation and dummies, and then allow the terms to be dropped? Some genetic algorithm to allow it in the model but not to consider all models.

Comment: Or as an alternative: do you think it makes sense to consider each such variable purely in isolation with the dependent variable, and perform the F score test for each as an aside before taking either linear/dummy/linear+dummy into the grand model?

Comment: If you want to consider dropping terms, I'd suggest doing it the orthogonal polynomial way, so that the linear term is directly part of the full model.

Comment: I wouldn't take the dummies -- you're just comparing them with the baseline group. It's not a suitable way to look at model reduction if you entertain a linear relationship

Comment: But I'll be looking not only at linear relationships, interaction term might be for example in the middle "group" with some other variable. E.g. 1-5 and then group 2 is the one that has an interaction. I thought only using the dummy style we can find that. Note that I'm going for interaction terms or simply a decision tree approach to go beyond the linearness.

Comment: Perhaps you need to ask a new question that makes clearer what you want to achieve...